# Using a Static Class to Initialize Members of another Static Class in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-classes

Is there anyway for a static class to use values set in another static class from a different namespace to initialize some of it's members? Is there anyway to dictate the order they get established in?

e.g.

```
namespace Utility
{
    using Config;

    public static class Utility
    {
        public static UtilityObject myUtil = new UtilityObject(ConfigContext.myValue)
    }
}
...
// somewhere in a different file/project
...
namespace Config
{
    public static class ConfigContext
    {
        public static string myValue => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of the basic pattern I'm trying to accomplish; I would like to take values that are in a config file which are loaded into `static class ConfigContext` , and use them to initialize members of a `static class Utility` .

Comment: Move the `using namespace_two` statement outside of the `namespace_one` block and the code you have should work.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this but at least to me, it's a code smell. Looking to "dictate the order they get established in" suggests a temporal dependency. What does that even mean? Static class instances are created when you try to use them.

Comment: Yeah this is a hyper simplified example of what I'm trying to do but the core concept is the same. Basically I want to use values in a Config file that get loaded into a static ConfigContext to initialize members of a static Utility class.

Comment: How about renaming your classes to illustrate what you just typed in your comment? It would make it a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: I would use static Lazy<T> and leverage the safe initialization options it provides in a multi threaded environment

Comment: @JuanR done and done.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I fail to see the problem. It looks like it should work although I wouldn't recommend this pattern. Not very unit-testable.

Comment: Come to think of it, you might as well not use a `ConfigContext` class at all if all you are doing is calling the `ConfigurationManager` class. Just use it directly in your other static class.

Comment: By the way, in case it's not obvious, I am not a big fan of static classes... :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dictate the order of static initialization. But you can avoid the problem entirely by deferring initialization using lazy logic.

```
public static class Utility
{
    private static Lazy<UtilityObject> _myUtil = null;

    private static Utility()
    {
        _myUtil = new Lazy<UtilityObject>( () => new UtilityObject(ConfigContext.myValue) );
    }

    public static myUtil => _myUtil.Value;
}
```

Using this technique, the utility object isn't initialized until it is actually used.

If the logic to initialize `ConfigContext` has a similar issue, you can use a Lazy there too, and all of your lazy fields will get initialized in a cascading fashion, in the order they are needed.